# HttpResponseRedirect doesn't work after new_join.save()

Tags: django

I tried to make simple request form. And I need to redirect user to "thank you" page after successful form sent. But after user hit "send" button - nothing happens. Just reload form page without form cleaning also.

Form is on "call" page, redirect needs "confirm" page...

So, task is: user fill the form on page "call" and after hitting "send" button, goes to "confirm" page.

My model:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.

class Join(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'expert_request'

user_expert = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user_cost = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user_email = models.EmailField()
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user_email
```

my "forms.py":

```
from django import forms
from userform.models import Join

class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Join
```

This is my "views.py":

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

# Create your views here.
from userform.forms import JoinForm
from userform.models import Join

def userform(request):

    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=False)
        new_join.save()
        HttpResponseRedirect('/confirm/')

    context = {"form": form}
    template = "userform.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

    def confirm(request):

    return render(request, 'confirm.html')
```

This is my URL's:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

    url(r'^$', 'expert.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/?$', 'expert.views.index'),

    url(r'^call/$', 'userform.views.userform', name='call'),
    url(r'^confirm/$', 'userform.views.confirm', name='confirm'),

)
```

My template "userform.html":

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<form style="position:relative" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.user_expert }}
<p style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:20px; color:#FF0000;">{{     form.user_expert.errors.as_text }}</p>
{{ form.user_name }}
<p style="position:absolute; top:182px; left:20px; color:#FF0000;">{{ form.user_name.errors.as_text }}</p>
{{ form.user_cost }}
<p style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:380px; color:#FF0000;">{{ form.user_cost.errors.as_text }}</p>
{{ form.user_email }}
<p style="position:absolute; top:182px; left:380px; color:#FF0000;">{{ form.user_email.errors.as_text }}</p>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form might have errors so `form.is_valid()` is false.

Comment: I'm included my "forms.py" to post above. Yes, I have warning "forms.py:4: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form JoinForm needs updating
  class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm)"

But I'm following tutorial and this always works just fine... How can  I avoid it?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your problem, or with what Rohan said. Can you please fix your indentation above, though, so we can see what your code actually does.

Comment: Sorry for that. Now I add my "model.py", so u can see whole picture.

Comment: Does your form have a closing `</form>` tag?

Comment: Yes, it have... I just forgot to add four spaces, when edit the post...

Comment: Are you sure your form action should be `<form action="">` ?

Comment: @s_spirit, please add the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the `return` statement in `userform` view function? Fix its beginning like this:

```
def userform(request):

    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=False)
        new_join.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/confirm/')
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out and write about it, but my message was erased. Thx anyway.